SMTPAuthenticationError at /appointment/ (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [BLAPR03CA0003.namprd03.prod.outlook.com 08DCAE8BF31BEC3D]')
My code works absolutely fine on local server, but I deployed it using a custom domain from godaddy and now everything's wrong with it.
I am using outlook mail. I don't know how to fix this. Other fixes I've seen only work for organization email and I have a personal email. I don't have the paid office365 version, I don't know if I need it just to send mail.
My settings.py:
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "email@outlook.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "pass"
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "email@outlook.com"


Outlook.com and Office 365 no longer allow basic authentication with SMTP.
